# Saving Masking layer with functional API to .keras file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using a custom mask in my Keras model. When I try to load the model with `model=tf.saved_model.load('model.keras')` from a `.keras` file, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <keras.src.layers.core.masking.Masking object at 0x7e7735fa1460> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.
```

Here is my model:

```
N_FEATURES = 6                                                                                       
MASK_VALUE = np.asarray([0.0 for i in range(N_FEATURES)])                                            
def get_clean_model():                                                                   
    # Input layer                                                                                    
    input_layer = Input(shape=(None, N_FEATURES))                                                            
    masked_input = Masking(mask_value=MASK_VALUE)(input_layer)                                       
                                                                                                 
    # LSTM layer with regularization                                                                 
    lstm_layer = LSTM(units=N_FEATURES, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True,                    
                  recurrent_regularizer='l2', kernel_regularizer='l2')(masked_input)             
                                                                                                 
    # Dropout layer                                                                                  
    dropout_layer = Dropout(0.05)(lstm_layer)                                                        

    # Dense layers with regularization                                                               
    dense_layer1 = Dense(N_FEATURES, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer='l2')(dropout_layer)   
                                                                                                 
    # Skip connection: Concatenate masked input with dense_layer1                                    
    concatenated_layer = Concatenate()([masked_input, dense_layer1])                                 
    dense_layer2 = Dense(N_FEATURES*2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer='l2')(dense_layer1)  
                                                                                                 
    # Dropout layer                                                                                  
    dropout_layer2 = Dropout(0.05)(dense_layer2)                                                     
                                                                                                 
    # Output layer                                                                                   
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dropout_layer2)                                    
                                                                                                 
    # Create the model                                                                               
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391265/keras-serializing-a-masking-layer-for-save-load) shows how to do it for custom layers, but I don't have any custom layers. How can I serialize and retrieve this model? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be caused by new version of `wrapt` package,
for more context see [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/issues/231)

Could you try with setting this environment variable?

```
WRAPT_DISABLE_EXTENSIONS=true
```